# UIImagePickerController Camera Bug??? (Looks like it is "Sent to Back")

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

I am creating a window-based application (I am using window-based because I like how the universal apps are organized), but I am having trouble with the UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera. I want to have two views:

the parent view: a menu screen
the sub view: the screen where you can choose the photo from a gallery or where you can use the camera to take a photo

The main issue is, when I push the button to take a picture with the camera, it works and I can see the camera controls, and I can even take a picture with no problem. However, whatever objects that are in the parent view are covering the "viewfinding" screen. (i.e. if I am pointing my camera to a flower, I can see the flower on the screen, but there are buttons and imageviews from the parent view overlayed on it. I hope that makes sense).

I am adding the ImagePickerController as a modal view. You can see the code below. When I choose photo from album, it seems to be working okay, but when I try to take a picture with the camera, it is like it is sent to the back of everything.

```
-(IBAction)setImage:(id)sender{

  UIImagePickerController* picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
  picker.delegate = self;

  if((UIButton *) sender == ChoosePhoto) {
      picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
  } else {
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
  }

  [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];

}
```

Maybe I am just missing something really obvious. Any help would greatly be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are putting all your "subviews" into the UIWindow rather than into the root view controller's view. Don't do that, add them to the root view controller's view.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Sorry if this a very silly question, but what do you mean by root view controller. Are you saying to use multiple UIWindows instead of subviews? Sorry, just a little confused =\

Comment: @user744349: No. At the top level, you have the one UIWindow object. On 4.0 and later, you should not add any views to this yourself, only set the `rootViewController` property (on pre-4.0, you instead do `[window addSubview:myRootViewController.view]` just the once in `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`). In IB, there should not be any subviews in the window. That UIViewController object that you assign to the window's `rootViewController` property is your root view controller. It has a `view` property. You should add your subviews into *that* view, either in IB or programmatically.

Comment: I think I am getting closer to making this work. I researched and found out that, like you said, pre-4.0 uses '[window addSubview:viewController.view];', but post-4.0 should use 'self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;'. Now when I am switching views from main menu to my camera page (which calls the camera up through presentModalViewController), should I do it using '[self.view addSubview:mycamerapage_iPad.view];'? I think that's where I am stuck. Do you happen to know any examples or tutorials on rootViewController? I am just wrapping my head around root views in xcode4

Comment: @user744349: You could replace the rootViewController of the window with your camera page, or you could present the camera page modally (which would then present the camera modally on top of itself), or you could use a UINavigationController as the root.

Comment: Thanks Anomie for your advice. After reading your comment, I decided to do more research about modal views and apply the camera page modally. This time, any views I had before the main page that I modally loaded the camera page would be on top. I always thought that presenting a page modally would put it on the top. So I experimented. I used the exact code on an iPad and on an iPhone version. The iPhone version works no problem. The iPad is always getting covered. Even when I run an iPhone only version on the iPad, it works. Is there a bug with how iPad's camera handles modal views?